# Proving $C_{X}=R_{X}-E\left(X\right)\left(E\left(X\right)\right)^{T}$ where $C_X,R_X$ are the Covariance matrix and Correlation matrix

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'm trying to solve [Example 6.11 from the Probability Course](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_5_random_vectors.php):

> For a random vector $X$, show that:
> $$
> C_{X}=R_{X}-E\left(X\right)\left(E\left(X\right)\right)^{T}
> $$
> where $C_X$ is the Covariance matrix of $X$ and $R_X$ is the Correlation matrix of $X$.

In the solution they stated that:
$$
\begin{align}
\nonumber \mathbf{C_X}&=\mathbf{E[(X-EX)(X-EX)^{T}]} \\
\nonumber &=\mathbf{E[(X-EX)(X^T-EX^T)]} \\
\nonumber &=\mathbf{E[X X^T]-EX EX^T-EX EX^T+EX EX^T} \hspace{10pt} \textrm{(by linearity of expectation)} \\
\nonumber &=\mathbf{R_X-EX EX^T}.
\end{align}
$$

I got to:
$$
\begin{align*}
C_{X}&\overset{(1)}{=}E\left[\left(\vec{X}-E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)\left(\vec{X}-E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}\right]\\&\overset{(2)}{=}E\left[\left(\vec{X}-E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)\left(\vec{X}^{T}-\left(E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}\right)\right]\\&\overset{(3)}{=}E\left[\vec{X}\vec{X}^{T}-\vec{X}\left(E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}-E\left(\vec{X}\right)\vec{X}^{T}+E\left(\vec{X}\right)\left(E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}\right]\\&\overset{(4)}{=}E\left[\vec{X}\vec{X}^{T}\right]-E\left[\vec{X}\left(E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}\right]-E\left[E\left(\vec{X}\right)\vec{X}^{T}\right]+E\left[E\left(\vec{X}\right)\left(E\left(\vec{X}\right)\right)^{T}\right]
\end{align*}
$$

I'm trying to figure how did they solve it? I don't see how can I continue from here. I also don't understand if my assumption of $EX EX^T=E(X)(E(X))^T)$ is correct because you can read it in a few different ways (like $E(XE(X^T))$, $E(X)E(X^T)$, $E(X)(E(X))^T$, etc). Is it possible to explain how did they continue?

Comment: Why is $R_X=\mathsf{E}XX^{\top}$ a correlation matrix?

Comment: By definition, apparently.

Comment: Yes, $E[X^T]=E[X]^T.$ Write out to convince yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf E(X~\mathsf E(X)^\top)=\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(X)^\top$ by Linearity of Expectation, since $\mathsf E(X)^\top$ is a constant matrix.

$\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X)~X^\top)=\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(X)^\top$ likewise.

$\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(X^\top))=\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(X)^\top$ too.

---

Also $\mathsf E(X)^\top=\mathsf E(X^\top)$, because the $i,j$ member of the expectation of the transposition,  $\mathsf E(X^\top)$, will clearly be the $i,j$ member of the transposition of the expectation, $\mathsf E(X)^\top$.

Let $X=[x_{ij}]$. $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X^\top) &=\mathsf E([x_{ij}]^\top)\\&=\mathsf E([x_{ji}])\\&=[\mathsf E(x_{ji})]\\&=[\mathsf E(x_{ij})]^\top\\&=\mathsf E([x_{ij}])^\top\\&=\mathsf E(X)^\top\end{align}$$

Comment: $\mathsf E(X)^\top=\mathsf E(X^\top)$ is true if $X$ is a random matrix or only if it's a random vector? Because in this question we $X$ is a random vector but I see you provided a proof for a matrix (more generic case). Is it corret?

Comment: It works for matrices of any rank, vectors included.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By linearity of expectation, for constants $A,b$, $$E[AX+b]=AE[X]+b,$$ and the expectation of a random vector is constant.